# Increment inventory with <button>

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am setting up an inventory form and I need to be able to have a button that can increment the levels by 1 and a button to subtract one. Here is what it looks like so far. When I press the "+" I would like the "Stock" column row to increase by one and update my database. Same goes for the "-". Also any assistance on getting the delete button to work would be awesome as well. Button is commented out at the moment.

I have this hosted here [Demo](http://everestt.co).
When you add a new item it creates a new entry into the database and creates the buttons.

I tried creating a public function and connect to that function like this:

```
echo "<td><button>+</button onClick="somefunction()"><button>-</button></td>";
```

But I get an syntax unexpected echo error.

[image: Db screenshot]

Right now the table is populate with php.

```
<table id="data" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0" role="grid">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Campus</th>
        <th>Toner</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
    </tr>

</thead>

<tbody id="searchTable">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM `Inventory` WHERE ID='$_POST[hidden]'");

    }
    $fetch = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `Inventory`");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><center>".$row['Model']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>".$row['Brand']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>".$row['Campus']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>".$row['Toner']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>".$row['Stock']."</center></td>";

        echo "<td><button>+</button><button>-</button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }//end



?>

    <tr>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <td><center><?php echo $row['Model'];?></center></td>
             <td><center><?php echo $row['Brand'];?></center></td>
             <td><center><?php echo $row['Campus'];?></center></td>
             <td><center><?php echo $row['Toner'];?></center></td>
             <td><center><?php echo $row['Stock'];?></center></td>
             <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value='<?php echo $row['ID'];?>'</td>
            <!--<td><center><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" id="delete"></center></td>-->

            </center>

        </form>
    </tr>



</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: remember PHP runs at the server, and JavaScript runs on the client's browser.  So when the user presses +/- button, that tells JavaScript to do an ajax call back to the server, gives data to a php program, and that program runs to talk to the MySQL database.  I'd like to see all the JavaScript files (particularly someFunction() and an ajax call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your writeup, and a failure to even mention JavaScript, I'm guessing you are new to web development.

- I'd recommend doing a basic php for the web tutorial, so you have a familiarity with how the PHP language works, and what it does.
- Then I'd recommend doing a basic JavaScript for html in the browser tutorial.
- Next, with the sample code you are using, you will need to have a decent familiarity with jQuery.
- Finally, you will need a bit of training in understanding how AJAX calls work.  That's a way for the user to make a request on the site, and get some functioning without an entire screen refresh.

With your proposed Toner page, you want to do a complete re-submit whenever someone adds a new toner via the Insert button.  (This is the same as a form submit, where the submission shows the same form again... there are plenty of php samples out there that show you how to do this.)

You probably don't want to do a complete re-submit whenever someone hits a +/- button.  For that, an ajax call is a recommended design (note: since you are already using jQuery, their Ajax call is pretty easy to use..)  You will need to write a .php file to manage the +/- selection. That php file will access the database to perform the updates.

Good luck with it.

Comment: I did some more research as you suggested and instead of using increment buttons i added an update button. Then I wrapped the items being pushed to the table with input tags and am connecting to the primary key through another ISSET($_POST['update'])){//what to update}